# managing multiple versions of the multiple products relative to some API in git

Tags: git

We have multiple standalone products into a system, that we integrate with via an API, this API changes between version, so we get an explosion of combinations of products and systems, and we're struggling to track it all.

e.g.

lets say we have the products.
{ product1, product2, ...., product50 }

and these products integrate with an external system, that we support on 5 different versions of API.
{ version1, version2, ..., version5 }

each combination of product and version has an associated software code base.
so we have an explosion of products x versions = 50 pieces of code.
(ok some code bases will actually work across more than 1 version of API as an added wrinkle)

we currently manage this simply through folders, currently we have a folder for each version and then a folder for each product under that version folder. To be honest, its quite easy to get lost, if someone asks for product5 to be available on version5, then we take version4 (assuming it exists) and upgrade it, but then we find that version4 is actually missing functionality that exists in version1, version2 and version3.

I suspect the situation should be quite common in a microservices context, where a family of microservices cooexist and all have a common dependency on some externally versioned system.

My inclination is that simply organising our code by product and then version is a tiny step in the right direction, I'm very nervous about viewing each version as a different branch in 1 repository per product.

---

so based on the some feedback from astrochun, lets assume there is a repository per product.

So the question is how to organise the versions, are they simply a folder per version in the repository? or should there be a repository per productversion?

with a single version the standard branch workflow pretty much captures what is/isnt outstanding.

Comment: Is your question just, generally "How could I use git to ensure new API versions continue to provide functionality the client(s) are dependent on?" ?

Comment: For starter, it sounds like each "product" should have their own `git` repo for proper versioning.

Comment: @astrochun...I agree.

Comment: @C-RAD...I suppose the issue is, in a normal workflow, someone creates a branch to implement some functionality, and really the tracking all works in the git history, but I need 5 branches, 1 for each product, and that doesnt seem "natural"

Comment: So you are running different branches of the same codebase in production? You might consider serving all products from the same server. That is, create a naming scheme so that you can merge all 5 branches to master, deploy master so that your api microservice can serve all 5 products, then make your client microservices smart enough to know which endpoints they need to hit on the api service to get the product they need.

Comment: no, each production environment contains 1 "external system" which requires a specific version of each product.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that git alone can not solve this problem for you. Git will naively record changes to the project but can't do anything to ensure correctness of your code.

As far as ensuring an arbitrary version of an API can support an arbitrary version of a client microservice, there are several common approaches that I know of.

1. Manual Testing: Works best if the api in question is servicing a UI, or isn't too far downstream from one. Is not very useful in isolating the problem
2. Integration Testing: This is where you stand up an environment with all of your microservices and then run automated tests so your client microservices can make real requests to your apis.
3. Contract Testing: You generate an api contract when you run your CI, and save it somewhere so that when your client runs on CI, it can pull the contract and verify that it can utilize the api (there are several frameworks available for contract testing).
4. Shared types: Utilize git submodules or a monorepo so that they type checker can guarantee your apis & clients agree on the types of objects they are sending and receiving (of course only possible with a type checker).

Comment: and given the above, how would you suggest organising the repository/s?

Comment: It depends on how similar your products are. If you have multiple products sharing a lot of code, then handling all the same products in the same repo is fine. You can still deploy the same codebase to n different servers so that you have product specific servers, as long as your client services know which server they are supposed to utilize. I would suggest a naming scheme for your endpoints like `product/5/version/2`. Consider getting comfortable serving multiple versions at once (from the same master branch), and prefer creating new versions over modifying old ones.